# Scala For Comprehensions and For Loops

Tags: scala, collections

## Objective

Trying to decrypt [for comprehension and loop](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops) and their difference.

```
Expr1          ::=  `for' (`(' Enumerators `)' | `{' Enumerators `}')
                       {nl} [`yield'] Expr
Enumerators    ::=  Generator {semi Generator}
Generator      ::=  Pattern1 `<-' Expr {[semi] Guard | semi Pattern1 `=' Expr}
Guard          ::=  `if' PostfixExpr
```

### Questions

***For loop***

> A for loop for (enumsenums) ee executes expression ee for each binding generated by the enumerators enumsenums.

"Executes expression" means For Loop will not produce a value as the result but just apply some operation on each binding, hence it is basically a ***statement*** (in my understanding, in Scala, a expression returns a value, but a statement does not)?

For example, below there will produce none.

```
val mnemonic = Map('2' -> "ABC", '3' -> "DEF")
val a = for ((digit, str) <- mnemonic) str.contains(digit)
```

***For comprehension***

> A for comprehension for (enumsenums) yield ee evaluates expression ee for each binding generated by the enumerators enumsenums and collects the results.

Whereas For Comprehension will produce a collection object as the result by collecting the result of evaluating the ***Expr*** expression for each binding. If so, what is the type of the collection crated? If it is a method, I can look into API document but which document specifies the type returned by For comprehension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A for loop executes a statement for each item in a collection:

```
for (x <- List(1,2,3)) {
  println(x)
}
```

will print the numbers 1, 2, and 3.  The return type of the loop is `Unit`, which is kind of like `void` would be in Java, so it doesn't make sense to assign it to anything.

A for comprehension, using the keyword `yield`, is just syntactic sugar for `map` or `flatmap`.  These two statements are equivalent:

```
val y1 = for (x <- List(1,2,3)) yield x+1
val y2 = List(1,2,3).map(x => x+1)
```

Comment: A useful addition would be that for loops are mostly used for side effecting operations, whereas for comprehensions are generally pure expressions.

Comment: If we don't use yield, it is the same situation with desugaring, `flatMap`s are just replaced with foreach and the body of loop goes into last lambda, for example: `for (x <- List(1,2,3); y <- List(2,3,4)) println(x + y)` is desugared to `List(1, 2, 3).foreach(x => List(2, 3, 4).foreach(y => print(x, y)))`

Answer (score 1):

For comprehensions in Scala are syntactic sugar for `map`, `flatMap`, and `filter`.  What type they return depends on what kind of collections you use in the comprehension, so:

```scala
val result1: List[Int] = for (x <- List(1,2,3)) yield x
val result2: String = for (x <- "string") yield x
val result3: Future[Unit] = for (x <- futureReturningFunction()) yield x
```

Comment: I think for expressions can return any arbitrary collection type independent of the input collection. We can do ops in the yield expression to return elements of any type.